# is byte-compile-dynamic compatible with use-package?

Tags: use-package, byte-compilation

If I'm using `use-package` in a file that I plan to byte-compile, can I still leverage Emacs' `byte-compile-dynamic` setting to lazy-load compiled function definitions? From the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Loading.html):

> With dynamic function loading, loading the file doesn’t fully read the function definitions in the file.  Instead, each function definition contains a place-holder which refers to the file.  The first time each function is called, it reads the full definition from the file, to replace the place-holder.

So, for example, if my init.el loads a file,

```
(require 'my-persistence (concat user-emacs-directory "my-persistence")
```

in which I've put persistence-related settings,

```
(use-package savehist
  :commands savehist-mode
  :config
  (setq savehist-autosave-interval 60)
  (defun foo () ...)
  (defun bar () ...)
  (defun baz () ...))

(provide 'my-persistence)
```

I could add `-*-byte-compile-dynamic: t;-*-` to the top of that file, in hopes that lazy-loading the compiled function definitions of `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` reduces the time spent evaluating the `:config` section.

I imagine it playing out like:

- my-persistence.elc is loaded
- user calls `savehist-mode`
- `savehist` package is loaded
- `:config` section is evaluated
- `savehist-autosave-interval` is set to 60
- lazy-loading defers the full definitions of `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`
- user calls `foo`
- `foo`'s full definition is loaded

I tried it out, and `:config` still behaves as expected, but I don't know how to check whether `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are in fact being lazy-loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like functions defined in the `:config` section will not participate in `byte-compile-dynamic` lazy-loading. I tested this by modifying the above example:

```
-*-byte-compile-dynamic: t;-*-

(defun foo () 5)

(use-package savehist
  :commands savehist-mode
  :config
  (defun bar () 5))

(provide 'my-persistence)
```

After `savehist` has been loaded, calling `(symbol-function 'foo)` returns:

```
#[nil
  ("/Users/ivan/.emacs.d/my-persistence.elc" . 473)
  nil 1]
```

Calling `(symbol-function 'bar)` returns:

```
#[nil "\300\207"
      [5]
      1]
```

Notice that `foo` currently holds a reference to the file where the full definition can be found, whereas `bar` holds the actual byte-compiled instructions and the `5` constant.

Indeed, after calling `(foo)`, a subsequent `(symbol-function 'foo)` shows that the full definition has now been loaded:

```
#[nil "\300\207"
      [5]
      1]
```

What *did* work, however, was puting the function I want lazy-loaded into a separate file and requiring it from the `:config` section:

```
(use-package savehist
  :commands savehist-mode
  :config
  (require 'my-foo))

(provide 'my-persistence)
```

And in my-foo.elc

```
-*-byte-compile-dynamic: t;-*-

(defun bar () 5)
```

I don't know how practical that is, though I guess it might be depending how many functions you're defining (and how many you won't be needing right away). I also don't know how this approach stacks up against autoloads, but it was interesting to try, anyway.